# If a matrix $A$, not necessarily symmetric, has real, nonnegative eigenvalues, is it positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

We know that a symmetric matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite i.e. $x^TAx \geq 0$ if and only if all its eigenvalues are nonnegative.

**Now suppose I have a matrix (not necessarily symmetric) $A$, whereby all its eigenvalues are nonnegative (obviously real), is it positive semidefinite?**

My hunch is yes. Because such matrix $A$ would satisfy $\lambda_{\min}(A)\|x\|^2 \leq x^TAx$. Therefore it has to be positive semidefinite.

But I have searched up and down through every linear algebra book that I have came across, virtually all of them states definition with respect to *symmetric* positive semidefinite matrix only.

Comment: As far as I know, positive semidefinite applies **only** to symmetric matrices, and if this is accurate then your question makes no sense

Comment: @DonAntonio There are examples of asymmetric matrices such that $x^TAx \geq 0$. In some of these cases, $A$ does not even have any real eigenvalues. Then if $A$ is positive semidefinite means $x^TAx \geq 0$, then positive semidefinite can be extended to asymmetric matrices.

Comment: The inequality $\lambda_{min}(A)\|x\|^2\leq x^TAx$ might be problematic.

Comment: In $\lambda_{\min}(A)\|x\|^2 \leq x^TAx$ the valued $\lambda_{\min}$ is the minimum eigenvalue of the symmetric part of $A$, not of the full $A$.

Comment: @JohnathanMeek Never heard of. I've only read of that applied to symmetric or, in the complex case, Hermitian matrices.

Comment: @DonAntonio https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues

Comment: In the complex case, if one has $x^TAx\geq 0$ for all complex vectors $x$, then one *must* have $A$ being Hermitian.

Comment: @JohnathanMeek Exactly my point and the first comment there addresses this: about the nature of the eigenvalues we can always talk, but to put the discussion within the context of *positive semidefinite or definite* is another matter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, consider the following matrix:

$$A=\pmatrix{1&-10\\0&2}$$

It has positive eigenvalues, but is certainly not positive semidefinite.

Comment: I'm confused between your example and the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518890/prove-that-every-positive-semidefinite-matrix-has-nonnegative-eigenvalues?rq=1

Comment: @JohnathanMeek in the other answer, symmetry of the matrix seems to be implicitly assumed. Many people define positive definiteness to imply/include symmetry.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is NO. (And it is worse in the complex case: if a matrix $A$ is *not* Hermitian, then it is impossible that $x^TAx\geq 0$ for all $x$.)

In the setting of **complex** vector spaces, if $x^TAx\geq 0$ for all complex vectors $x$ (your definition of semi-definite), which in particular implies that $x^TAx\in{\bf R}$, the following theorem in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* shows that $A$ must be Hermitian (if $A$ is real, then $A$ must be symmetric):

[image]

In the setting of **real** vector space, one has the following simple counterexample.

For any $(x,y)\in{\bf R}^2$,
$$
(x,y)\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y
\end{pmatrix}=xy. 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Given that, for a real matrix $A$ we have
$$
x^T A x=x^T A^{(S)} x
$$
where $A^{(S)}$ is the symmetric part of $A$, then the character of $A$ with respect to positive definiteness, or semi-definiteness, is related only to the eigenvalues of its symmetric part.

As the examples in other answers show, a matrix could have positive eigenvalues, but its symmetric part could have a negative eigenvalue, so eigenvalues of a matrix could not be related to positive (semi)definiteness.